# No full screen button on Youtube player embed on iframe

Tags: iframe, youtube

i use an iframe to embed code where there is a youtube player and some html but the problem is that the full screen button is not present on the youtube player.

Iframe used : http://jsfiddle.net/94150148/8rmbv7mk/

```
<iframe src="http://www.webvideoproduction.fr/v/vga/230415y.html" width="523" height="880" style="border-width: 0; overflow: hidden; width: 100%;"></iframe>
```

Do you have a solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add **allowfullscreen** in your youtube iframe tag, where your youtube video is embbeded..
 Use the following code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/PD8r5A4sonw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Hope this helps.

**Update**

Hi, try this updated code. it worked for me.

```
<iframe width='420' height='315' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/PD8r5A4sonw?rel=0&amp;' allowfullscreen  ></iframe>
```